# Is "consume" correct in "Heating water consumes a large amount of energy"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Can I say?

> Heating water consumes a large amount of energy.

(Where heating water is an activity.)

Comment: So you mean 'when I heat up water it costs me a lot of energy'? Or do you mean 'you need a lot of energy to heat up water'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use consume in your sentence.

According to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/consume), one of the definitions for the word 'consume' is:

Use up (a resource)
Example: this process consumes enormous amounts of energy

Comment: Hello, Megha. Questions not accompanied by reasonable basic research are contrary to ELU guidelines, and doing that simple research for enquirers encourages further  unsuitable questions.